# How can I use Guzzle to send a PUT request?

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle, guzzle6

Does anybody know the correct way to PUT using Guzzle? my code is not working
but my post methods are working

```
 $enrolment = $client->request('PUT', $url,[
       'form_params' => [
           'contactID' =>12345,
           'type' =>'w'
        ],
       'headers' => [
           'apitoken' => $api_token,
           'wstoken' => $ws_token
        ]
 ]);
```

> resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:↵{"DATA":"","ERROR":true,"MESSAGES":"key [TYPE] doesn't exist","CODE":"0","DETAILS":""}

Answer (score 0):

The PUT request does't accept `form_params` type as request option, so it may ignore the setting.

From [Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html?highlight=form_params#form-params):

> form_params
>
> Used to send an application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> **POST** request.

Maybe you can try using json  for `PUT` request.

In the [json part of Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html?highlight=form_params#json), it uses `PUT` as well.

```
$enrolment = $client->request('PUT', $url,[
       'json' => [
           'contactID' =>12345,
           'type' =>'w'
        ],
       'headers' => [
           'apitoken' => $api_token,
           'wstoken' => $ws_token
        ]
 ]);
```

Comment: If It's not working, I will check these two things : 1. Check the request and see is the json data part indeed sending.   2. See if the response server do accept json format data. Since you said the POST version with `form_params ` is working fine, maybe it only accepts form data.